# Image not displayed on canvas using fs/nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, html

I am using nodesjs and fs to create a server that renders a html page.

My html page has a script(javascript) to create a canvas,image and draw image on canvas. Now when I provide imageObj.src as local image in file system (absolute path or relative to html page) the image is not loaded. However if i define imageObj.src  as coming from some http url it gets displayed fine. Not sure where the issue is here? Please help ..See code below

**Server Side Code:**

```
var handler = function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile('./page.html', function (err, data) {
        if(err) throw err;
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(data);
    });
    }

var app = require('http').createServer(handler);
var fs = require('fs');
var port = 3250;
app.listen(port);
```

**Client Side HTML (Page.html) Snippet**

```
imageObj.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(imageObj, 69, 50,100,100);

  };
  imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg'; // THIS WORKS
  //imageObj.src = 'D:/Pics/darth-vader.jpg'; // THIS DOESNT WORK
  //imageObj.src = 'file:///D:/Pics/darth-vader.jpg'; // THIS DOESNT WORK EITHER
//imageObj.src = 'img/darth-vader.jpg'; // THIS DOESNT WORK EITHER
```

Answer (score 0):

On client side, you cannot set a .src with a local file, you need to set a URL. It is up to your nodejs server to serve the local image.

The client still runs in the navigator sandbox and has no access to local disk. NodeJS has specific libraries that give access to local access but this not standard Javascript.